# measurability of a random variable taking values in the space of continuous functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability sapce and let $X: \Omega \to C^+(\mathbb{R})$ be a random variable taking values in the space of real valued non-negative continuous functions on the real line. I want to verify that the map $(\omega, x) \to X(\omega)(x)$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. I do this in order to use Fubin's theorem to get

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}X(x)\mathrm{d}x \right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}\left[X(x) \right]\mathrm{d}x.$$

My attempt: Follow proposition 1.13 on page 5 in Brownian Motion
and Stochastic Calculus (Ioannis Karatzas and Steven E. Shreve), with the suitable adjustments to our case. For $x \in \mathbb{R}, \omega \in \Omega, n \geq 1$ and $k = -2^n + 1, ... -1, 0, 1, ... 2^n - 1$, define:

$$X^{(n)}(\omega)(x) = X(\omega)(\frac{k+1}{2^n}) \quad \text{ for } \quad \frac{k}{2^n} < x \leq \frac{k+1}{2^n}$$.

We get that $(\omega, x) \to X^{(n)}(\omega)(x)$ is measurable and converges to $(\omega, x) \to X(\omega)(x)$ as $n \to \infty$, hence this map is measurable and we are done. Is it true? I couldn't find a proper reference, and I think I'm correct but I'm not used to these kinds of proofs of measurability, so if someone could help and verify this it will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $X$ is random variable with values in $C^{+}(\mathbb R)$? If you mean that $\omega \to X(\omega)(t)$ is measurable for each $t$ then, yes, this  argument is correct. It works even if $X(\omega)$ is just right continuous for every $\omega$.

Comment: No, I mean that the map taking $\omega \to X(\omega)$ is measurable with respect to some Borel sigma algebra on the continuous functions (say, the one generated by the open sets with respect to the supremum norm)

Comment: Supramum norm is not defined on this  space.

Comment: Usually, $C(\mathbb R)$ is endowed with the topology of "compact convergence" defined by the seminorms of the form $f\mapsto\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|$ where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$, which makes $C(\mathbb R)$ Polish.

Comment: You can google "Caratheodory function."

Comment: Essentially, if my proof is correct whenever $\omega \to X(\omega)(x)$ is measurable for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so I want to know when does the fact that $\omega \to X(\omega)$ is measurable implies the above. This means that I only need to know when the coordinate map $f \to f(x)$ is measurable. This is clearly true in the product topology on the continuous functions. How does this relate to other topologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on $C^+(\Bbb R)$ you use the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal C$ generated by the coordinate projections $C^+(\Bbb R)\ni x\mapsto x(t)$, $t\in\Bbb R$, then your approximation argument does show that a random element $X$ mapping $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ to $(C^+(\Bbb R),\mathcal C)$ does have the property that $(\omega,t)\mapsto X(\omega)(t)$ is $\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ measurable. In particular, $X(t):\omega\to X(\omega)(t)$ is a real-valued  random variable for each $t$. Of course, $t\mapsto X(\omega)(t)$ is "better than" Borel measurable for each $\omega$, being continuous.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I am interested to know what happens in other $\sigma$-fields. Actually, I am interested in a bit more complacted case. I consider the space $C_{\text{tem}} \equiv \{f \in C(\mathbb{R})^+ : |f|_{\lambda} < \infty, \forall \lambda < 0\}$, where $\left| f \right|_{\lambda} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}e^{\lambda |x|}|f(x)|$ is a (semi)norm on this space, and I consider the topology generated by these norms, which is metrizable by the standard Frechet metric. Are the corrdinate projections measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-field on $C_{\text{tem}}$ with this topology?